# `this.previous().previous().element == this.element`?

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I'm upgrading my code from jquery-waypoints 2.x to 4.x and have identified strange behavior related to `this.previous()`. I find that in a handler that was triggered at the correct time, `this.element` is correct. However, `this.previous().element` points to the next element in the DOM with a waypoint and `this.previous().previous().element` points to the same element as `this.element`. I can set a break point in the code and have validated that `this.previous().previous().element == this.element`.

I have to imagine I'm doing something very wrong, or this is a bug. I'm on v4.0.1 and I'm using the jQuery version. I'm binding my waypoints like so:

```
$selector.waypoints(
    function goingUp(direction) {
        console.log(this.previous().previous().element == this.element); // true
        console.log(this.next().previous().element == this.element); // true
    }, {
        offset: offsetCalculator(this),
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the grouping of waypoints. The `.previous()` waypoint, not counting for grouping, appeared later in document order than the current waypoint. Once I added groups to the waypoints, `.previous()` and `.next()` worked as expected.